# How to make Nightwatch use xpath by default in page object files

Tags: xpath, pageobjects, nightwatch.js

All my page objects look something like this:

```
  elements: {
      header: {
         locateStrategy: 'xpath',
         selector: "//h3[text()='Welcome']"
      },
      loginButton: {
         locateStrategy: 'xpath',
         selector: "//button[text()='Login']"
      },
      forgotPasswordLink: {
         locateStrategy: 'xpath',
         selector: "//a[text()='Forgot Password?']"
      },
      signupButton: {
         locateStrategy: 'xpath',
         selector: "//button[text()='Signup']"
      }
```

It would be way better if I could just say "use xpath everywhere"  - that would all collapse mightily

[The docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide) say that you should be able to set `"use_xpath" : true` in your "test settings", but I have tried that in all the places I can see in nightwatch.json, and it doesn't have any effect.

(It's not completely clear if they mean that this setting will affect declarations in page object files, in any case: the example only shows it affecting subequent assert calls in the test case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a javascript function like this (depending on your favourite way to create objects):

```
var xSelector = function (selector) {
    return {
        selector: selector,
        locateStrategy: 'xpath'
    }
};
```

And then use it like so:

```
elements: {

    xxx: xSelector('//a[text()="Bank Details"]')
    createStepButton: { selector: '#menu-create-item' },
}
```

*Hint: In the sample above the createStepButton is still using the css selector strategy. Consider also creating a cssSelector function for uniform readability of the elements section.*

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I would venture out and say that there's a bug in nightwatch.js.  Would anyone from the nightwatch team care to comment?  my test suite is growing and having this: locateStrategy: 'xpath', all over my code is not fun.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set:

```
"use_xpath": true
```

in `nightwatch.conf.js` file, not `nightwatch.json`

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it'll help someone.

Try to set:

```
"use_xpath": true
```

in your **nightwatch.json**

Answer (score 0):

To get around this you can loop over your elements and set any given locate strategy for each element, like this:

```
var pageObject = {
    url: 'https://google.com',
    elements: {
        myFirstElement: {
            selector: "//div[@class='my-first-el']"
        },
        mySecondElement: {
            selector: "//div[@class='my-seconds-el']"
        }
    }
};

for (var el in pageObject.elements){
    pageObject.elements[el]["locateStrategy"] = "xpath";
}
module.exports = pageObject;
```